# Retrieve Field Rows from a Pipe Delimited File

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I need to get first 9 words from a pipe delimited file and then next 9 words. Any help is appreciated.

```
cat a.txt
a|b|c|d|e|f|g|h|i|j|k|l|m|n|o|p|q|r|s|t|u|v|w|x|y|z|

cat new.ksh
#! /bin/ksh
a=`awk -F "|" ' { print NF-1 } ' a.txt`
echo $a

Expected Output:
a|b|c|d|e|f|g|h|i|
j|k|l|m|n|o|p|q|r|
s|t|u|v|w|x|y|z
```

Comment: What was the reasoning behind using `print NF-1`? How does it correlate with your expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sed -r 's/([^|]*\|){9}/&\n/g' a.txt
```

Explanation:
`[^|]` Not a |.
`[^|]*\|` One field (without `|`), followed by a `|`.
`([^|]*\|){9}` 9 fields, each followed by a `|`.
`&\n` Replace by the matched string followed by a newline.

Comment: Very nice elegant solution.  Minor note, it gives a trailing bar (`|`) that was not in the "expected" output but if the trailing bar is left off the input, it doesn't appear in the output.

Answer (score 0):

I pure `ksh` version:

```
IFS='|'
typeset -a str=( $( < a.txt ) )
len=${#str[@]}
bar='|'
for ((ii=0; ii<len; ii+=9))
do
    max=9
    (( ii+9 > len )) && max=$(( len-ii ))
    for ((jj=0; jj<max; jj++))
    do
        element=$(( ii+jj ))
        (( element == len-1 )) && bar=''
        echo -e "${str[$element]}${bar}\c"
    done
    echo
done
```

Explanation:

- `IFS`: This is the Internal field separator, normally this is space and tab but if it is reassigned, it separates other types of data.
- `typeset -a` We are creating an array to hold the data.
- `str=( $( < a.txt ) )` We read in the data from the a.txt array as elements of the array.
- `len=${#str[@]}` We need to know how long the array is so we know how much to print out.
- Outer for loop, you wanted to see the values in groups of 9.  This steps through the array nine at a time.
- To avoid running off the end, I created a variable max that will hold how many elements are on the current line.  The we guess 9 and then updated it if necessary.
- `(( ii+9 > len )) && max=$(( len-ii ))` This is doing an integer comparison of ii+9 against the length.  If the condition is true, we update max with the lower value.
- Inner for loop, this where we step through the elements of the line.
- `element=...` We want the ii+jj element so here we calculate the value.
- `(( element == len-1 )) && bar=''` You had no bar at the end.  To avoid printing the bar, we use a bar variable that we turn to nothing when done.
- `echo -e "${str[$element]}${bar}\c"` Here we print that element along with the bar variable. The \c says do not end the print with a newline. The -e is required to get the \c to work.
- `echo` Since we did not get linefeeds for each element, we need to put it out now that we have 9 elements.

This version also works with bash.